# How to pass table name dynamically to the stored procedure or a simple SQL query, then store the results in a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to pass table name dynamically to the stored procedure or a simple SQL query, then store the results in a variable?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. First off you should add the code you already tried so we can have a look.

Comment: Wanting to parameterize by the table name is usually a sign of a broken data model. If you have multiple tables with the *same* structure, there's a good chance that it should have been a single table and some of the *data* that belongs in that table has instead ended up in *metadata*, as (part of) the table names. I.e. if you find yourself with `MaleEmployees` and `FemaleEmployees` tables, you've made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You may looking for something like this ?

```
USE [master]
GO

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(100) ='sys.tables'

DECLARE @RecordCount INT

SET @sql = N' SELECT @RecordCountOut = COUNT(*) 
            FROM ' + @TableName + '   AS t'


EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@RecordCountOut INT OUTPUT',  @RecordCountOut = @RecordCount OUTPUT

SELECT @RecordCount
```

Answer (score 0):

You could stored your `SQL` query result in this way

```
DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Result  = COLUMN FROM TableName
```

however, you could use print command to check what the query return

```
print @Result
```